# Interleaving first and second half of an array of even length in place

Tags: sorting, arrays, permutations, in-place

If **A** is an array with the following elements:
$$ a_1,a_2,...,a_n,b_1,b_2,...,b_n $$

How to shuffle **A** to form:
$$ a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...,a_n,b_n $$

with minimal swaps and using no additional space?

I read [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/332/in-place-algorithm-for-interleaving-an-array) and wrote the following code:

```
def shuffle(a,left,right):
if right - left>=4:
    half = (right - left)/2
    for i in xrange(half/2):
        tmp = a[left + half + i]
        a[left + half+i] = a[left + half/2 + i]
        a[left + half/2 + i] = tmp
    shuffle(a,left,left + (right - left)/2)
    shuffle(a,left + (right - left)/2, right)

a = ['a1','a2','a3','a4',
     'b1','b2','b3','b4']
shuffle(a,0,len(a))
```

This gives an algorithm with O(nLog(n)) swaps. But I realized that this works only when n = 2<sup>k</sup> for some integer k. Is there a minor tweak that one could make to get the same complexity for arbitrary *n*?

Comment: Can you discover something about the cycles that for with that permutation for various $n$?

Comment: I didn't quite catch you - "that for with that permutation"?

Comment: $a2$ moves to index 3 which replaces $a3$ which moves to index 5 which replaces $a5$ which moves to index 9, eventually that will loop back to index 2. That's a cycle, Investigate how the cycles evolve as n increases.

Comment: Consider the permutation $\sigma: \{1,2,\dots,2n\} \to \{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ that you're trying to implement, i.e., $\sigma(i)=2i-1$ for $i\le n$ and $\sigma(i)= 2(i-n)$ for $i>n$.  Can you characterize its [cycle structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation)?  How many cycles does it have of each possible length?  Then use the fact that you can permute a cycle of length $\ell$ using $\ell-1$ swaps, and sum over all the cycles.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71154/755.

Comment: That link already describes how to handle the case of arbitrary $n$.  I'm not sure what your question is, exactly -- it seems like it is already answered by the answers over there.

Comment: I am not interested in the permutation cycles method as it works only for $ 2n + 1 = 3^k $. The answer also shows that combining both would result in an O(n) algorithm for arbitrary n. But implementing this is non-trivial. So I'm interested in knowing only if  "there is a minor tweak that one could make to get the same complexity(O(nlog(n)) for arbitrary n"

Comment: Does this algorithm meet your requirements?https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/105263/58310.  or  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55073167/10396